# Class attributes in Python objects "erasing" themselves

Tags: python-3.x, oop, printing, attributes

I'm working with some old Python2 code from a differential power analysis (DPA) contest from way back (http://www.dpacontest.org/home/index.html). The code I'm modifying can be found here (https://svn.comelec.enst.fr/dpacontest/code/reference/)

Current issue that is driving me nuts:
Essentially, Some python objects in this code will "erase" themselves or go to their default values, and I have no idea why. I cannot find any code in the logic flow that does this, and I don't think it's a scope issue.

I've tried rewriting parts of the code to use numpy instead of mapping lambda functions. I've also tried a myriad of different orderings of code and pulling methods out of their classes and trying to run them locally/inline.

main.py:

```py
loc_subkeys = brk.get_subkeys()
```

des_breaker.py

```py
def get_subkeys(self):
    """
    Returns a vector of currently best sboxes subkeys.
    This is an array of 8 integers.
    """
    sk = np.array([])
    for i in range(8):
        sk = np.append(sk, self.__sbox_breakers[i].get_key())
    return sk
```

sbox_breaker.py

```py
def get_key(self):
    "Gives the current best key"
    if self.__best_key is None:
        marks = np.array([])
        print("p0: ", len(list(self.__key_estimators[0]._key_estimator__p0)))
        print("p1: ", len(list(self.__key_estimators[0]._key_estimator__p1)))
        print("p0: ", len(list(self.__key_estimators[0]._key_estimator__p0)))
        print("p1: ", len(list(self.__key_estimators[0]._key_estimator__p1)))
        for i in range(64):
            ke = self.__key_estimators[i]
            marks = np.append(marks, ke.get_mark())
            self.__best_key = np.argmax(marks)
        return self.__best_key
```

key_estimator.py - attributes

```py
class key_estimator:
    """
    Provides methods to give a mark to the key relatively to the probability f
    the correctness of the key.
    """
    __sbox = None
    __key = None
    __cnt0 = 0    # The accumulated traces count in partition 0
    __cnt1 = 0    # The accumulated traces count in partition 1
    __p0 = None  # The bit=0 estimated partition
    __p1 = None  # The bit=1 estimated partition
    __diff = np.array([])  # The differential trace
```

Print statements in sbox_breaker are mine. Their output is the only clue I have right now:

p0:  5003 (Good)

p1:  5003 (Good)

p0:  0 (???)

p1:  0

What gives? The second time around the attributes of the key_estimator class have seemed to erase themselves. This happens to all the attributes, not just p0 and p1.

The first loop through this program works, but on the second iteration (starting from main) it fails because the attributes have erased themselves. I can "erase" them manually just by printing the object's attributes.

Comment: can you provide the htaccess login for the link to the code you give

Comment: Yeah sorry it's on the webpage. User: guest, pass: guest. Also I think I figured out my issue. The problem is the Python2 map -> Python3 map. The attributes are maps that don't seem to persist, so making them into lists has fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

So I seemed to have fixed the problem after sleeping on it. The class attributes were being created by map which returns a list in Python2, but not Python3. Making them into lists with list() solves the persistence issue. I couldn't tell you why printing a map attribute causes it to clear itself though.

Comment: Because maps are lazy iterators, they are single pass